# Skew in parallelogram on hover

Tags: html, css, transform

This is my navbar... When I hover over a link it should turn to normal text but it is showing me diagonal text....

```css
.navbar-menu2 li a:hover{
  color: black;
  width:  100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  /* Zentriert den Inhalt */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-menu2 li a span:hover{
  transform: skewX(30deg);
}
```

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark p-0">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav1">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-menu2 text-white">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second diagonal"><span>Home</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Classes</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Trainers</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Pricing</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Gallery</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Blog</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Contact</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

It works fine when we hover over the text. i.e my `span` tag.. I want the same in `li` tag: get normal text when we hover over it.
 Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the reversed transform (`transform: skewX(30deg);`) on

```
.navbar-menu2 li a:hover span
```

instead of

```
.navbar-menu2 li a span:hover
```

because the `span` doesn't always get hovered when the related `a` is hovered:

```css
.navbar-menu2 li a:hover{
  color: black;
  width:  100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: red;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  /* Zentriert den Inhalt */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-menu2 li a:hover span{
  transform: skewX(30deg);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark p-0">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav1">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-menu2 text-white">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second diagonal"><span>Home</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Classes</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Trainers</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Pricing</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Gallery</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Blog</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Contact</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

Remove:- `transform: skewX(-30deg);` from your CSS.

```css
.navbar-menu2 li a:hover{
  color: black;
  width:  100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  transform-origin: top;
  /* Zentriert den Inhalt */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-menu2 li a span:hover{
  transform: skewX(30deg);
}
```

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark p-0">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav1">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-menu2 text-white">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Home</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Classes</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Trainers</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Pricing</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Gallery</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Blog</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link navbar-second"><span>Contact</span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: you change the css of background from paralellogram to square... i want background diagnol only. Now if you hover to span tag, it changes the text to diagnol...